# Windows 7 (and up) taskbar thumbnail preview not working

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, thumbnails, taskbar

My app developped with Unity doesn't display the taskbar thumbnail preview in Windows 7. It just shows a blank square. Is there a setting that I'm forgetting to change here or something that I need to setup in app ?

How do I make this work ?

EDIT : Forgot to mention, this does work when the application is in Windowed mode, however when it is fullscreen and tabbed out the preview will be empty.